# Where is payload reside in a DNS frame when tunneling?

Tags: dns, dns-domain

Can anyone explain me about DNS tunneling? 
where the TCP/IP packet or payload data injected in a DNS frame? 
How data get decapsulated in the server side? 
Explain DNS frame?

Answer (score 1):

There is no single DNS tunnel solutions. But usually data from client to server gets encoded within the queried hostname while data from server to client gets encoded  and embedded in the DNS response as TXT or other records.

Deeper technical details are easy to find when searching for [dns tunneling](https://www.google.com/search?q=dns+tunneling). For example [this paper](https://www.sans.org/reading-room/whitepapers/dns/detecting-dns-tunneling-34152) gives a deeper view in the technologies involved and how different products use these techniques.